# Property [vegan] does not exist on this collection instance. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to show a title based on whether a specific column in my table is 1 or 0. In my Controller I have (edited out some irrelevant code):

```
 public function show(Company $id){

        $vegan = Company::find($id);
        $vegetarian = Company::find($id);

        return view('allProducts')->with([

            'vegan' => $vegan,
            'vegetarian' => $vegetarian,
        ]);
    }
```

and in my view:

```
  @if($vegan->vegan == 1)
    <h3 class="text-center">Vegan</h3>
  @endif
```

However I get error message

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Property [vegan] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\EdenBeauty\resources\views\allProducts.blade.php)
```

Ive tried the following but I get errors every time:

```
@if($vegan[0]->vegan == 1)
```

This gives undefined offset errors

Comment: As a pointer, you're calling the db twice which is inefficient, `$vegan = Company::find($id);` is the same as `$vegetarian` - you'd be better off naming the variable `$company` and only doing the query once :)

Comment: If you really need these variables to be filled, you can use findOrFail, instead of find only. If the Id do not exist, it will throw an error with status 404. To go deeper would be interesting in your route file.

Comment: Also, what is the primary key of Company? If the ID exists in the table Company, try doing `Comany::where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're missing `first()` after your queries:

```
$vegan = Company::find($id)->first();
$vegetarian = Company::find($id)->first();
```

Comment: Now I get Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\EdenBeauty\app\Http\Controllers\ProductsController.php on line 55 and at least 1 expected

Comment: Try first instead, updated my answer. Btw, try to do `dd($id, $vegan, $vegetarian)` before your return statement, and see if any data is passed.

Comment: The `find()` function is the same as `where('id', $id)->first()`

Comment: @N69s I don't, no. Sorry what should go in there?

Answer (score 1):

In this line, you're injecting a `Company` into your `show` method via URL parameter:

```
public function show(Company $id){ ... }
```

At that point, `$id` is either a `Company` instance or `null`. Calling `$vegan = Company::find($id)` doesn't make any sense, and I'm actually surprised you don't get an error at that point in the code.

Also, if you're using injection, name the variable correctly `Company $company` to avoid confusion, and reference later:

```
public function show(Company $company){
  $vegan = $company;
  $vegetarian = $company;
  // Or `$vegan = Company::find($company->id);`
  // (This is redundant, but demonstrates the syntax)

  return view("...")->with(...);
}
```

Alternatively, remove injection and query:

```
public function show($id){
  $vegan = Company::find($id); // Note can use use `firstOrFail()`, etc.
  $vegetarian = Company::find($id);     
  ...
}
```

Either way, `find()` does not return a `Collection`, so `$vegan->vegan` would not return "Property [vegan] does not exist on this collection instance.", but something about your usage is treating it that way.